# Getting percentages of ID's which "drop" out of their respective clusters at different time points in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, cluster-analysis, percentage

I am clustering a user generated data set and one of the questions I am looking to answer is what percentage of users drop out of their respective clusters over time. To use an example, say if I clustered user data from a website, I want to look at the number of users who drop off from using the website i.e. those users who do not appear again in the data after different time points. And I would like to know which clusters lose the most users at different time points too.

I have tried survival analysis which works well but I would also like to save the list of user ID's, that have dropped out, to another object or data frame with the respective time point of when they dropped out.

Here is a mock dataframe along with the clustering code. The time points I want to use as a reference is known as MonthYear in the data:-

```
#creating replicable example
library(dplyr)
library(ids)
library(data.table)
UserID_1<-random_id(n=100,bytes = 10)
UserID_1

Date_1<-sample(seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2017-12-31"), by = "1 day"), 
                size = 900,replace = T)
df1<-data.frame(Date_1)
df1$UserId<-sample(UserID_1,size = nrow(df),replace = T)

UserID_2<-random_id(n=25,bytes=10)
UserID_2
Date_2<-sample(seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2017-04-01"), by = "1 day"), 
               size = 100,replace = T)
Date_2
df2<-data.frame(Date_2)
df2$UserId<-sample(UserID_2,size = nrow(df2),replace = T)


colnames(df1)[1]<-"Date"
colnames(df2)[1]<-"Date"


df<-rbind(df1,df2)
df<-df%>%arrange(Date)

#clustering time

clusterdata<-df%>%
  group_by(UserId)%>%
  summarise(Count=n())

clusterdata
scaledata<-scale(clusterdata[,2])
#k-means
set.seed(20)
clust<-kmeans(scaledata, centers = 5, nstart = 15)
#assigning cluster to UserId
clusterdata$Cluster<-clust$cluster
#getting cluster variables
cluster_vars<-clusterdata%>%select(UserId,Cluster)
df<-merge(df,cluster_vars,by="UserId")
#get month year variable
df$MonthYear<-as.Date(as.yearmon(df$Date, "%m/%Y"))


#naming clusters
setDT(df)[Cluster==1, ClusterName:="Cluster 1"]
df[Cluster==2, ClusterName:="Cluster 2"]
df[Cluster==3, ClusterName:="Cluster 3"]
df[Cluster==4, ClusterName:="Cluster 4"]
df[Cluster==5, ClusterName:="Cluster 5"]

df
```

Is there an efficient way to get percentages of user ID's that have dropped out of the cluster at each time point (in this case the MonthYear variable) within the data. Also, the user ID's which do not appear again at particular time points, can these be saved to another object so they can be inspected at another time?

Comment: maybe you would like to use a smaller dataset without needing more packages? `data.table(ID=c("A","B","C","A","D","B","E"), Cluster=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3), Dropped=1L)[
    ID %chin% DT[duplicated(ID)]$ID, Dropped := 0L][, 
        sum(Dropped) / .N, Cluster]`

Comment: @chinsoon12 could you please replicate your answer with the mock data sample that I have provided? This would make it easier to understand your solution. Thank you